# dotent core blob storage caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, caching

I have image processor app, for processing image and getting it from azure blob storage. In this moment my blob storage service is returning absolute url to image of blob return redirect to this url. For example:

```
 [Route("/blob-storage/{imageName}")]
 [HttpGet]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetImage(string imageName, ImageSize size)
 {
     var imageUrl = await this.ImageProcessorFacade.GetImageUrl(imageName, size);

     return Redirect(imageUrl);
 }
```

Now I want to caching this returned image. Yes, exists `ResponseCache` attribute, but It doesn't me work with redirect and I thing that it is bad way to solving this problem. For get image, I call for example this: `http://localhost/blob-storage/test.jpeg?size...`
And response is redirect to `blob.windows.net/...` etc.

Is there way, how to cache it?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is that you want to be cached? The image itself or the "processor" resulting URL?

Comment: Processor is returning redirect to image, so final returned image.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to caching this returned image. Yes, exists ResponseCache attribute, but It doesn't me work with redirect and I thing that it is bad way to solving this problem. For get image, I call for example this: http://localhost/blob-storage/test.jpeg?size... And response is redirect to blob.windows.net/... etc.

You call Redirect() method in your controller action to redirect to a specified URL, the HTTP **Location** header field will be returned in response. And then the user agent (e.g. a web browser) that is invited by a response with 3xx code will make a second request to the new URL specified in the location field, which happens on web browser side, you could not append or modify cache-related headers to response.

[image]

If you'd like to lower latency and faster delivery the images that stored in Azure blob storage, you could try to use [the CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/cdn).